# How can I display an angular component that is initialized from code?

Tags: angular, typescript, dynamic, components

I have the following setup:

*Users Component HTML:*

```html
<div class="users">
  <ul class="users__list">
    <li *ngFor="let user of users"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

*Users Component TS:*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserComponent } from '../user/user.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.scss'],
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
  users: UserComponent[] = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.users.push(new UserComponent('Test User'));
  }
}
```

*User Component HTML:*

```html
{{ name }}
```

*User Component TS:*

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.scss'],
})
export class UserComponent {
  constructor(@Inject('name') public name: string) {}
}
```

My goal is to be able to dynamically (for example using a button) generate new users via code like `new UserComponent('NAME');` and add them to the users array in the users component.

My question is: **How can I display a component that is initialized from code?**

I tried something like this:

```html
<div class="users">
  <ul class="users__list">
    <li *ngFor="let user of users">{{ user }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

but that just outputted '[object Object]'.

Maybe I have a completely wrong approach but I thought this could be the easiest solution, if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep track of data in the most part and Angular will handle the view for you.

Take a look at this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jnhfcz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuser%2Fuser.component.html)

Answer (score 1):

**How to show object property in template?**

Your use is an object, so you have to indicate in HTML what property of this object you want to show:

```
<div class="users">
  <ul class="users__list">
    <li *ngFor="let user of users">{{ user.name }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**How to generate more items and display in list?**

Angular, automatically, bind your TS variables with your template. So, just update your users list with new users that Angular will update view. For example:

```
/* User.ts */
export class User {
 name: string;

 constructor(name: string) {
  this.name=name;
 }
}
```

---

```
/* UsersComponent.ts */
addUser() {
 const newUser = new User("I'm a new user!");
 this.users.push(newUser);
}
```